# Is there a way to achieve multi-tenancy in OSGI in a similar manner as we did with spring?

Tags: java, spring, osgi, multi-tenant

Someone in my shop came up with a clever way to achieve multi-tenancy using the spring framework.    They basically created a main parent application context with commonly used services, and then for every new tenant, a child context with tenant-specific beans was created.  It works pretty well and we can spin up new tenants on the fly.

Now we have hard requirement to use OSGI, and this model is breaking down.  We've tried a couple of different approaches and either they don't work, or we would need to bring down the VM to add a new tenant to add new declared services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use OSGi Blueprint to do this quite easily.

You probably know that Blueprint is the successor of Spring Dynamic Modules... so, obviously, there's lots of similarities between Blueprint contexts and Spring contexts.

Here's a guide to OSGi Blueprint:

http://www.javabeat.net/2011/11/blueprint-and-service-dynamism-in-osgi/

I would advise you to create a single "parent" bundle which will represent your parent Spring context, and then for each tenant, you install a new bundle which uses the OSGi Services exported by your parent bundle.

As bundles can be dynamically installed and uninstalled at any time, you should be able to achieve a much better dynamism than you could with Spring alone.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Create a parent OSGi Framework and then a separate OSGi Framework for each tenant. Export the shared services from the parent framework into the tenant frameworks using their system bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a standard way to do this.

An alternative to the multiple framework approach (which also has to be implemented yourself) is introducing a "contextual" object (like the Spring application context) which implements a `getService` method that acquires a proper OSGi service based on some tenant specific filter configuration.

We did [something similar in Gyrex](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gyrex/Context_Runtime). But again, it's a custom solution (Open Source, though) and not an OSGi standard.